# MVC controller action overload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

Can I do something similar to this in a way that doesn't throw an error:

```
public class AdsController : Controller
{
  AdsRepository repo = new AdsRepository();

  public ActionResult Details(string id)
  {
    AdSlots adslot = new AdSlots();
    Enum.TryParse(id, true, out adslot);
    return Content(repo.GetInvocationCode(adslot, Global.SiteInfo.ID));
  }

  [ChildActionOnly]
  public ActionResult Details(AdSlots slot)
  {
    return Content(repo.GetInvocationCode(slot, Global.SiteInfo.ID));
  }

}
```

The point is that I want to have a way of accessing the resource through /ads/details/leaderboard as a url in the browser, but also in master pages using:

```
 <% Html.RenderAction("Details", "Ads", new {slot = AdSlots.Leaderboard }); %>
```

I just think that is cleaner than:

```
 <% Html.RenderAction("Details", "Ads", new {slot = "Leaderboard" }); %>
```

If I do as above and call the url /ads/details/leaderboard I get this error:

> The current request for action 'Details' on controller type 'AdsController' is ambiguous between the following action methods.. etc

I didn't think I would get that error as I have given the attribute [ChildActionOnly] to the other action. I would think then it was obvious for the system that if I access it through the browser I would only have one option, not so apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the nicest, but
`<% Html.RenderAction("Details", "Ads", new {id = AdSlots.Leaderboard.ToString() }); %>`
should always result in the first action... And since the problem being that MVC calls a ToString() on your enum ANYWAY, so you could just leave out the second controller action alltogether, and then your problem might go away... Parsing an enum is not **that** expensive...

Answer (score 0):

The `ChildActionOnlyAttribute` only enforces that the action is called as part of a child request through `Html.Action` and `Html.RenderAction` in your view.  This attribute is not considered when MVC attempts to match a method to the incoming route call.